# Pixel perfect glTranslatef

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

how can I make it so I can plug in pixel coordinates into gl.glTranslatef() ?
Currently, I do this to get the texture appear at the bottom of the screen:

```
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(1.45f, -2.76f, 0);
    gl.glScalef(1 / scaleX, 1 / scaleY, 0);
    Square sq = getTexture(resourceId);

    sq.draw(gl);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Without having to plug in the "1.45f, -2.76f, 0" values, the texture appears at the centre of the screen. How can I position my textures using pixel coordinates? Most of my texture's dimensions are 32x32, and a few 16x16.

Before I have used ((GL11Ext) gl).glDrawTexfOES() to render my textures, however I was unable to perform any transformations to the textures, for example I couldn't rotate them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you set up your projection, but what you should be doing is use [glOrtho](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) and [glViewport](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glViewport.xml) to set up your scene. given a window of size (width, height):

```
// init opengl at some previous point
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
// choose bottom-left corner, e.g. (0,0)
// use your own values for near and far planes
float left = 0, bottom = 0, near = 0.1f, far = 1000.0f;
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glOrtho(left, left + width, bottom, bottom + height, near, far);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

and you will get pixel-coords (bottom-left at (left,bottom)) for your application